# Silverstripe 3: Duplicate emails being sent after form submission

Tags: php, silverstripe

When a form is submitted on my silverstripe 3 site, 4 copies of the same email are being sent.

I have email addresses A, B, C and D in the recipients of the silverstripe user form, all of whom should receive an email when a form is submitted. This is working correctly.

I also have email address E which is in my _ss_environment file as `SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO`.

However, when a user submits a form email address E is receiving 4 copies of the exact same email.

I think I understand why this is happening as E should receive all emails sent from the site and 4 emails are being sent, but this is receiving the exact same email 4 times. Surely there is a way around this so that email address E just receives the one email.

How can I keep `SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO` and send the form submissions to 4 different recipients while only sending one email to email address E?

Comment: When you send 4 seperate emails to A,B,C and D, a copy of every mail will be sent to the address defined in `SS_SEND_ALL_EMAILS_TO`. You might either send one email to A and cc it to the others, or temporarly disable `Email.send_all_emails_to` config setting which is automatically set by your environment constant.

Comment: @wmk how am I able to temporarily disable `Email.send_all_emails_to`?

Comment: See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/#accessing-and-setting-configuration-properties how you can update SilverStripe's config vars in PHP